# Looking for help unpacking a NHST notation using probabilities

Tags: hypothesis-testing, notation

In brief, I am used to a definition of the *P*-value as: the probability of observing our sample data (or something more extreme) if the null hypothesis is true. Consequently, seeing null hypotheses of the form
$$ H_0 \ : \ \theta \ge \theta^* $$
(or some variation with an equality statement).

Recently, however, I encountered the following notation for the null

$$ H_0 \ :\ \text{Pr}(\theta > \theta^*) = 0.5 $$

and alternative

$$ H_a \ :\ \text{Pr}(\theta > \theta^*) < 0.5 $$

Furthermore, the author referred to this as a left-tailed test.

My hope is that someone can explain the rationale behind this notation.  In particular, I'm having trouble unpacking a null hypothesis that is a fixed probability (at 50%) for an inequality statement about a parameter.  And, ¿why would it be a left-tailed test if this probability is less than 50%?...particularly when the statement about the parameter would suggest a right-tailed interpretation.

Any clarification that can be provided would be welcome.

Comment: Could the $0.5$ (instead of $0.05$) be a typo?

Comment: Nope...just double checked the document, and it is using 0.5 throughout. (10-plus occurrences via a quick scan)

Comment: Please explain what the author means by "$\theta$" and "$\theta^{*}.$"  Evidently the meaning differs from your initial use of these symbols, because in that first use they are *parameters* whereas in the second use they must be *random variables.*

Comment: $\theta$ is a parameter of interest and $\theta^*$ is the value to which it is being compared.  An example in the text is $\theta$ is the standard deviation and $\theta^*$ is a fixed value to which it is being compared (16.5).

Comment: Then the probability statements make no sense.

Comment: This is an odd Bayesian construction. "Odd" meaning non-standard. The hypotheses stated by the author reflect two different states of prior belief. But usually, when performing Bayesian hypothesis testing, one states their prior belief using a probability statement such as the author's $H_0$, then updates that probability using the data.